# How to programatically move/categorize django-filer files?

Tags: django, image, django-filer

We use django-filer 0.9.8 for our image uploads. Now we'd like to programatically add some images to the catalog and move them to filter category.

I managed to get the creation and saving of a `FilerImage` working, but when I check the admin all the images end up in an 'uncategorised' folder in the file management overview.

So I guess I'll have to move the file (the virtual file) but I cannot find any documentation about it. I'd assume I could pass something when I create the image, or move it after saving.

Any ideas? I'm looking at the docs and the source code but I cannot find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FilerImage is just a ForeignKey to File, when you create it you can create also a filer.models.foldermodels.Folder and specify where the File is created.